# With Tauri how can i save a file to a specific path?

Tags: javascript, file, svelte, tauri

I have this code:

```js
async function downloadMod(url, folder, basePath) {
        const httpclient = await getClient();
        const file = await httpclient.get(url, {
          responseType: ResponseType.Binary
        });
        invoke("expand_scope", { folderPath: basePath }) // Used to allow writes in whatever folder i want
        await writeTextFile( url.split('#')[0].split('?')[0].split('/').pop(), Uint8Array.from(file.data), { dir:  BaseDirectory.Desktop });
}
```

How can i save the file to basePath + folder and if basePath's `folder` folder dosent exists create one?

Im on windows btw...

I tried using the string as the path but it didnt work, it didnt spit out an error but didnt create the file...

Comment: In the code i used to test BaseDirectory.Desktop but i want basePath + folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fs plugin](https://tauri.app/fr/v1/api/js/fs/) to create the folder recursively:

```js
import { createDir, BaseDirectory } from '@tauri-apps/api/fs';

createDir('YOUR_APP', {
  dir: BaseDirectory.LocalData,
  recursive: true
}
```

Don't forget to setup permissions inside `tauri.conf.json` as well:

```json
"allowlist": {
    "fs": {
        "all": true,
        "scope": ["$LOCALDATA/*"]
    }
},
```

Comment: I want to download data in C:/Programs (86x)/... not on localAppData. The permissions are dynamically handled

Comment: In the docs it says it requires core-level handling

Comment: Program Files is a protected directory, so it won't work via default FS plugin.

Comment: You'd want to create tauri command and invoke it with your file data, and then inside the rust function you can use https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir_all.html to create the folder and then create the file.